Apache Flink AsyncRetryStrategy with RichAsyncFunction
AsyncRetryStrategy asyncRetryStrategy =
    new AsyncRetryStrategies.FixedDelayRetryStrategyBuilder(3, 100L) // maxAttempts=3, fixedDelay=100ms
        .ifResult(RetryPredicates.EMPTY_RESULT_PREDICATE)
        .ifException(RetryPredicates.HAS_EXCEPTION_PREDICATE)
        .build();

// apply the async I/O transformation with retry
DataStream<Tuple2<String, String>> resultStream =
    AsyncDataStream.unorderedWaitWithRetry(stream, new AsyncDatabaseRequest(), 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, 100, asyncRetryStrategy);

This is example from official Flink docs
Say we make 5 async API call inside the AsyncDatabaseRequest's asyncInvoke method, does flink test the predicates in AsyncRetryStrategy against the output stream element
which is of type Tuple2<String, String> in this example, , and retry whole asyncInvoke method OR will it test the predicates against the output of each of the 5 async API calls and retry the ones which failed out of the 5 ?

The retry is on a per-record basis. See Flink's AsyncWaitOperator.processElement(), which is called once per element. If retry is enabled, then it uses the RetryableResultHandlerDelegator, which implements the ResultFuture API, and in particular the completeExceptionally() call which will trigger a retry of that single record that failed.
